# Check if we have the same values during 5 fields from a column - Dataframe-

Tags: r

I have the following dataframe.

```
        FECHA         rto_1         rto_2         rto_3         rto_4         rto_5         rto_6         rto_7
1    2006-01-02            NA            NA            NA            NA            NA            NA            NA
2    2006-01-03  0.000000e+00  1.643048e-02  2.110990e-02  1.608205e-02  1.502095e-02  2.777215e-03  1.963310e-03
3    2006-01-04  1.552376e-02  3.672762e-03  9.464680e-03  7.614807e-03  5.235291e-03  1.054688e-02  1.152604e-02
4    2006-01-05  3.901222e-03  1.570524e-05  5.578389e-03  3.653135e-03  5.390611e-04 -6.078095e-04 -1.283579e-03
5    2006-01-06  1.729033e-04  9.399441e-03  1.741639e-02  1.100769e-02  9.800412e-03  4.588739e-03  3.587400e-03
6    2006-01-09  0.000000e+00  3.656307e-03  3.982732e-03  9.801202e-03 -4.754545e-03  1.306248e-03  1.426941e-04
7    2006-01-10 -1.849623e-02 -3.565477e-04  1.217062e-03  6.726994e-03  2.801506e-03 -7.309806e-03 -7.657424e-03
8    2006-01-11  1.483719e-02  3.481457e-03  8.153576e-03  2.812900e-04  2.019382e-03  6.493934e-03  6.948501e-03
9    2006-01-12  4.986681e-03 -6.274243e-03 -6.193694e-03 -6.186640e-03 -2.224416e-03  4.334067e-04  1.670013e-03
10   2006-01-13  5.934866e-04  1.205231e-03 -3.262083e-04  2.335847e-03  8.313799e-04 -1.115743e-02 -1.065294e-02
11   2006-01-16 -1.135950e-02  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  1.000877e-02  4.177172e-03  5.754055e-03
12   2006-01-17 -2.840418e-02 -3.634641e-03 -5.948087e-03 -6.806303e-03 -2.675546e-03 -9.422650e-03 -9.879158e-03
```

As you can see I have an efficiency dataframe.

I have to check if in each of the columns we have **5 values ​​followed which are 0.**

Then I have to return FECHA "date" from the first 0 appearance and the last one.

For example, for the following dataframe.

```
            FECHA         rto_1         rto_2         rto_3         rto_4         rto_5         rto_6         rto_7
    1    2006-01-02  0.000000e+00             NA            NA            NA            NA            NA            NA
    2    2006-01-03  0.000000e+00  1.643048e-02  2.110990e-02  1.608205e-02  1.502095e-02  2.777215e-03  1.963310e-03
    3    2006-01-04  0.000000e+00   3.672762e-03  9.464680e-03  7.614807e-03  5.235291e-03  1.054688e-02  1.152604e-02
    4    2006-01-05  0.000000e+00   1.570524e-05  5.578389e-03  3.653135e-03  5.390611e-04 -6.078095e-04 -1.283579e-03
    5    2006-01-06  0.000000e+00   9.399441e-03  1.741639e-02  1.100769e-02  9.800412e-03  4.588739e-03  3.587400e-03
```

In this case I have to return, something like:
**`Initial Date 2006-01-02 Last Date: 2006-01-06 --> consecutive days : 5` `for rto_1`**

As in the other cases we haven't five consecutive 0's, this is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(dplyr)
df$FECHA <- as.Date(df$FECHA)

df %>%
  arrange(FECHA) %>%
  replace_na(list(rto_1=0)) %>%
  mutate(FECHA_diff = as.numeric(FECHA - lag(FECHA))) %>%
  group_by(grp = cumsum(rto_1 == 0)) %>% 
  filter(all(FECHA_diff==1) | grp==1) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  mutate(rto_1 = 0) %>%
  select(-grp, -FECHA_diff) %>%
  data.frame()
```

Output is:

```
       FECHA rto_1        rto_2       rto_3       rto_4        rto_5         rto_6        rto_7
1 2006-01-02     0           NA          NA          NA           NA            NA           NA
2 2006-01-03     0 1.643048e-02 0.021109900 0.016082050 0.0150209500  0.0027772150  0.001963310
3 2006-01-04     0 3.672762e-03 0.009464680 0.007614807 0.0052352910  0.0105468800  0.011526040
4 2006-01-05     0 1.570524e-05 0.005578389 0.003653135 0.0005390611 -0.0006078095 -0.001283579
5 2006-01-06     0 9.399441e-03 0.017416390 0.011007690 0.0098004120  0.0045887390  0.003587400
```

Sample data:

```
df <- structure(list(FECHA = c("2006-01-02", "2006-01-03", "2006-01-04", 
"2006-01-05", "2006-01-06", "2006-01-09", "2006-01-10", "2006-01-11", 
"2006-01-12", "2006-01-13", "2006-01-16", "2006-01-17"), rto_1 = c(NA, 
0, 0.01552376, 0.003901222, 0.0001729033, 0, -0.01849623, 0.01483719, 
0.004986681, 0.0005934866, -0.0113595, -0.02840418), rto_2 = c(NA, 
0.01643048, 0.003672762, 1.570524e-05, 0.009399441, 0.003656307, 
-0.0003565477, 0.003481457, -0.006274243, 0.001205231, 0, -0.003634641
), rto_3 = c(NA, 0.0211099, 0.00946468, 0.005578389, 0.01741639, 
0.003982732, 0.001217062, 0.008153576, -0.006193694, -0.0003262083, 
0, -0.005948087), rto_4 = c(NA, 0.01608205, 0.007614807, 0.003653135, 
0.01100769, 0.009801202, 0.006726994, 0.00028129, -0.00618664, 
0.002335847, 0, -0.006806303), rto_5 = c(NA, 0.01502095, 0.005235291, 
0.0005390611, 0.009800412, -0.004754545, 0.002801506, 0.002019382, 
-0.002224416, 0.0008313799, 0.01000877, -0.002675546), rto_6 = c(NA, 
0.002777215, 0.01054688, -0.0006078095, 0.004588739, 0.001306248, 
-0.007309806, 0.006493934, 0.0004334067, -0.01115743, 0.004177172, 
-0.00942265), rto_7 = c(NA, 0.00196331, 0.01152604, -0.001283579, 
0.0035874, 0.0001426941, -0.007657424, 0.006948501, 0.001670013, 
-0.01065294, 0.005754055, -0.009879158)), .Names = c("FECHA", 
"rto_1", "rto_2", "rto_3", "rto_4", "rto_5", "rto_6", "rto_7"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", 
"6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12"))
```